# Project Euler Q2

Tags: vba, excel

Hello guys I am new to programming and have decided to use Project Euler to consolidate my knowledge.

I attempted question 2 in the following way:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub question2v2()

Dim val1 As Single
Dim val2 As Single
Dim counter As Single
Dim val3 As Single
Dim newval As Single
Dim lastval As Single
Dim intfin As Single ' sum of even values

Dim lenstr As Integer

val1 = 1
val2 = 1

    Do While intfin < 4000000

        val3 = val1 + val2

        val1 = val2
        val2 = val3

        If val3 Mod 2 = 0 Then

            newval = val3

            intfin = lastval + newval

            lastval = newval

            Debug.Print intfin

        End If

    Loop

End Sub
```

I am getting 4,356,618 which is close to the answer but not quite there.

Please review the algorithm and let me know where I am going wrong.

Your help is very much appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: For a start, there's no need to be using `Single` instead of `Long`.

Comment: What is the answer?

Comment: Don't know if still the same but you might be interested in reading https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/112822/project-euler-1-3-in-vba/112879

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you only need to make one small change, commented in the code below. I have also incorporated @jsheeran's comment.

```
Private Sub question2v2()

Dim val1 As Long
Dim val2 As Long
Dim counter As Long
Dim val3 As Long
Dim newval As Long
Dim lastval As Long
Dim intfin As Long ' sum of even values
Dim lenstr As Long

val1 = 1
val2 = 1

Do While intfin < 4000000
    val3 = val1 + val2
    val1 = val2
    val2 = val3
    If val3 Mod 2 = 0 Then
        newval = val3
        intfin = lastval + newval
        lastval = intfin 'changed from newval as intfin keeps the running total
        Debug.Print intfin
    End If
Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you guys for replying. The change introduced by @SJR outputs the correct answer (4613732). Any other comments regarding my code structure are appreciated.